# Protractor right click works fine. but can not selecting an option inside it

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

[image]

I am able to find the button inside the context menu , but i am unable to click that button the following code is able to click the button but the it comes with an error telling that

```
Failed: script timeout
    (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
```

```
 browser.actions().mouseMove( page.getEllipses()).perform();
 browser.actions().click(page.getEllipses(),protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
 browser.pause();
 browser.sleep(5000)
 page.getStatusButton().click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line below in your code,

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

and here are the links that are related to the same issue (for further explainations),

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5153

[Fail loading file protractor - Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712899/fail-loading-file-protractor-failed-script-timeout-result-was-not-received-i)